# Adding Sequence to a Table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sequence

Sorry for asking kind of a noob question and thanks for reading.

I need a small clarification on adding `SEQUENCE` value to a column. If I execute the following code the statement gets executed

```
CREATE TABLE EXECSQLORG_EMPLOYEE(
EMP_ID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_EMP_ID DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ,
EMP_NAME VARCHAR(100),
EMP_GENDER BIT,
EMP_SALARY MONEY,
EMP_SHIFT BIT) GO
```

Or If I define a table first and execute the `Alter` command, statement gets executed

```
ALTER TABLE EXEC_EMPLOYEE 
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_APP_ID DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ FOR APP_ID
```

So far so good!!

Once If I try to add Sequence to columns with following code I get error

```
CREATE TABLE EXECSQLORG_EMPLOYEE (
EMP_ID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_EMP_ID DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ,
EMP_NAME VARCHAR(100),
EMP_GENDER BIT,
EMP_SALARY MONEY,
EMP_SHIFT BIT
CONSTRAINT PK_APP_ID PRIMARY KEY (EMP_ID),
CONSTRAINT DF_APP_ID DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ FOR EMP_ID  
)
GO
```

When I execute the above code I get the following error

> Incorrect syntax near 'for'.

Comment: I don't see where you create the `SEQUENCE` object! It's not a column attribute - it's a separate, stand-alone database object that you need to create before usage - `CREATE SEQUENCE ......` Since the sequence is it's own object, you cannot *add a sequence to a table* - that's not how it works.

Comment: ^ ohh cool!! Got the answer

"Since the sequence is it's own object, you cannot add a sequence to a table"

Answer (score 0):

Just create your table without sequence. And run this query..

```
CREATE SEQUENCE EXECSQLORG_EMPLOYEE.EMP_ID 
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;
GO
```

To sequence with default values..

```
CREATE SEQUENCE EXECSQLORG_EMPLOYEE.EMP_ID  ;
```

For more info...
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

Answer (score 0):

<s>Sorry if i miss understood, but sequence is a POSTGRESQL concept for autoincremental (MySQL) values and IDENTITY for SQL Server</s>

so in your case :

```
CREATE TABLE EXECSQLORG_EMPLOYEE(
EMP_ID INT IDENTITY,
EMP_NAME VARCHAR(100),
EMP_GENDER BIT,
EMP_SALARY MONEY,
EMP_SHIFT BIT) GO
```

I keep this wrong answer for people in my case since Sequences is a new feature of SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Sequences exist in sales server 2012, so you may want to delete or correct your answer.

Comment: Of course that was sql server... stupid autocorrect changed it.